# Killing form of isomorphic Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I tried to figure out how the killing form of two isomorphic finite dimensional Lie algebras over a field $k$ is related. I.e. if there is an isomorphism $\phi:K\to L$, how is $\kappa_K$ related to $\kappa_L$?

Comment: The Killing form is an invariant of the Lie algebra, so $\kappa_K = \phi^* \kappa_L$. In particular, taking $K = L$ gives that the Killing form is $\textrm{ad}$-invariant.

Comment: In particular, $\det(\kappa_K)=\det(\kappa_L)$ for $K\cong L$.

Comment: Thank you both! May you explain why or give me references please?

Comment: Just rewrite $L$ with a basis in terms of $\phi$, so that $L=K$, and you see that the Killing forms are identical.

Comment: We have $\kappa_L (x,y)=\text{tr}_L(\text{ad}(x)\text{ad}(y))=\text{tr}_{\phi (K)}(\text{ad}(\phi(x'))\text{ad}(\phi(y')))$. So?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not sure how you define $\det(\kappa_K)$, since there is no preferred basis a priori.

Answer (score 2):

Let me quickly expand Dietrich Burde's comment above.

Fix elements $X, Y \in K$. If we can show that $\kappa_L(\phi(X), \phi(Y)) = \kappa_K(X, Y)$ that will be enough for us, assuming that we don't use any special properties of $X$ and $Y$.

Let $n$ be the dimension of $K$. We fix a basis $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ of $K$ and define the $2n^2$ numbers $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ by $[X, X_i] = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{i, j}X_j$ and $[Y, X_i] = \sum_{j = 1}^n b_{i, j}X_j$.

Let $A = (a_{i, j})$ and $B = (b_{i, j})$ be the corresponding $n \times n$ matrices. Anybody seeing just $A$ and $B$ would have no idea that there is a Lie algebra in the background (since they are completely ordinary matrices) but we know that $A$ represents $ad(X)$ and $B$ represents $ad(Y)$ w.r.t. to the basis $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

In particular we have that

$$\kappa_K(X, Y) = tr(AB).$$

Again: nothing on the right hand side refers visually to $K$.

So far so good.

Now since $\phi$ is an isomorphism we find that:
$$[\phi(X), \phi(X_i)] = \phi([X, X_i]) = \phi(\sum_j a_{i, j} X_j) = \sum_j a_{i, j} \phi(X_j)$$

The $a_{i,j}$ stayed the same throughout the above equations so we find that the same old matrix $A$ represents $ad(\phi(X))$ w.r.t. the basis $\phi(X_1), \ldots, \phi(X_n)$ of $L$.

Similar $B$ represents $ad(\phi(Y))$ and hence we find:

$$\kappa_L(\phi(X), \phi(Y)) = tr(AB).$$

Again, the left hand side comes from $L$ but on the right hand side we are just working with matrices and numbers. Now we can just cut the middle man and conclude that:

$$\kappa_K(X, Y) = \kappa_L(\phi(X), \phi(Y))$$

This answers your question. (Of course you can be distrustful of whether or not the answer would be different if we had used another basis than $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ but this is another issue about Killing forms in which the isomorphism $\phi$ plays no role.)