# Why are these Lie algebras isomorphic if and only if their Killing forms are isometric?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

(cf. [The Classification of Three-dimensional Lie Algebras](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/research/y4_fowlerwright.pdf) Theorem 3.2)

Let $L_{\theta\vartheta}$ be the Lie algebra with structure
$$
(*)\qquad [x, y] = z, [x, z] = −ϑy,[y, z] = θx.
$$
Let $<\theta,\vartheta,\theta\vartheta>$ denote the matrix representation of the Killing form of $L_{\theta,\vartheta}$, respect to the basis $\{x,y,z\}$.

> **Theorem.3.2.** The Killing forms $<\theta,\vartheta,\theta\vartheta>$ and $<\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta>$ are isometric if and only if $L_{\theta\vartheta}$ and $L_{\alpha\beta}$ are isomorphic.
>
> *Proof.* If $L_{\theta\vartheta}$ and $L_{\alpha\beta}$ are isomorphic then an isomorphism $\phi$ preserves the Lie products, i.e., $\phi[u,v]=[\phi(u),\phi(v)]$ for all $u,v\in L_{\alpha\beta}$. **It thus follows that $L_{\alpha\beta}$ and $L_{\theta\vartheta}$ will have the same adjoint matrices and hence the same Killing forms.**

**Question:** I don't understand why they have the same adjoint matrices. The adjoint matrices should be depends on the basis which I choose, so are the Killing form matrices.

The notation $L_{\alpha,\beta}$ means that there already exists a basis $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z\}$ satisfies the structure $(*)$. If we represent the Killing form of $L_{\alpha,\beta}$ by the basis $\{\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z)\}$, then the Killing form I obtain should be an another matrix, rather than $<\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta>$.

I've tried to use the property that

> If $B$ is the Killing form of $L$ and $s$ is a automorphism of $L$, then $B(s(u),s(v))=B(u,v)$.

to link $\{\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z)\}$ and $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z\}$, but I found nothing.

Comment: I've never seen $\theta$ (`\theta`) and $\vartheta$ (`\vartheta`) used as separate symbols.  Seems unwise to me.

Comment: I saw $\iota $ and $i$ used as separate symbols, which is perhaps even harder to distinguish.

Comment: I took time to locate your question (and I was confused by the title). If the question is not what I boldfaced, please fix it but emphasize what you consider as the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an Lie algebra isomorphism $f\colon L_1\rightarrow L_2$ to rewrite one Lie algebra, say $L_1$, so that its Lie brackets coincide with the ones of $L_2$. Then they have of course identical adjoint matrices. In a sense, it is trivial, that isomorphic Lie algebras share such invariant properties, because they are actually the same after just rewriting.

Comment: But once I rewrite $L_1$, then the Killing form would change, right? Since we use different basss to represent Killing form. It is trivial that $[B]_{\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z)}=[B]_{x,y,z}$, but do we have $[B]_{\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z)}=[B]_{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z}=:<\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta>$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is (almost) trivial. But I see one should verify this, of course.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I move the basis $\{x,y,z\}$ to $\{y,z,x\}$ and scale them so that I obtain many different Killing forms, and the only things I assure is $\alpha/\beta=\theta/\vartheta$. Can you give more details ?

Comment: Have alook around MSE here, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286471/killing-form-of-isomorphic-lie-algebras).