# Methods of determining when Lie algebras are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm just getting started in Lie algebras (and abstract algebra in general) and I was hoping to get some insight into how people generally determine if two Lie algebras are homo/isomorphic of each other. Are there common tests or logic that you employ? I've done some googling and textbook reading but it would be helpful to get some more base level insights from people with experience.

Comment: Well, of course there is no general surefire method, but you can start by checking basic things, like: do they have the same dimension? Does one have a special property that the other one doesn't (being simple, semisimple, solvable, nilpotent, etc.)?

Comment: Do you have some particular way of presenting a Lie algebra in mind? If it is by generators and relations one can simply try to find a correspondence between generators and check that the relations are preserved.

Comment: There is also a partial answer for the case of three-dimensional Lie algebras, see this previous post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668950/why-are-these-lie-algebras-isomorphic-if-and-only-if-their-killing-forms-are-iso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, one can explicitly compute this by solving polynomial equations in the entries of the linear map $f:L\rightarrow L'$ arising from the condition
$$
[f(e_i),f(e_j)]_{L'}=f([e_i,e_j]_L)
$$
for a basis $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ of $L$, together with the condition $\det(f)\neq 0$.
In low dimensions, it is indeed possible to solve such equations. If all obvious invariants are equal and we don't see an obvious isomorphism, then we have to do such a computation.

For example given two $7$-dimensional nilpotent complex Lie algebras $L$ and $L'$ of the same nilpotency class, we usually do not find easy invariants distinguishing them (often the adjoint cohomology $H^p(L,L)$ is a  good invariant, but it is also not so easy to compute it). Then
we can quickly decide whether or not they are isomorphic by the above computation.

Comment: In practice one can simplify the computation some requiring that the bases of the given Lie algebras are adapted to their structure. For example, if the nilradicals $\mathfrak{nil(g)}, \mathfrak{nil(h)}$ of two Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{h}$ (of the same dimension) have the same dimension $k$, then any isomorphism $f : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$ must satisfy $f({\mathfrak{nil(g)}}) = \mathfrak{nil(h)}$.

Comment: Thus, if we restrict ourselves to bases $(e_i)$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $(f_i)$ of $\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\mathfrak{nil(g)} = \operatorname{span}_{\Bbb R}(e_1, \ldots, e_k)$ and $\mathfrak{nil(h)} = \operatorname{span}_{\Bbb R}(f_1, \ldots, e_k)$, any $f$ must be block upper-triangular with respect to the bases---$$[f] = \pmatrix{\ast&\ast\\0&\ast}$$---eliminating $k (n - k)$ of the $n^2$ parameters of $f$.

Comment: @TravisWillse In the example both Lie algebras are already nilpotent, so that we cannot simplify the computation this way.

Comment: Yes, of course---perhaps I should have clarified that I meant my previous comment as an remark on the first paragraph of your answer, not the second one.

Comment: An observation that *does* apply to nilpotent Lie algebras (and all Lie algebras, though again in some cases this is vacuous) is that any $f$ must preserve the derived and the lower central series. In particular the sequences of dimensions of the subalgebras in these series is again an invariant. (Of course, you know all this, and I assume your example also assumes that these are also equal for the given $L, L'$, which can already happen in dimension $4$, at least over $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are several ways to simplify the computation. It really depends on the example we have. I just wanted to say that sometimes the direct computation is so easy that we should not be afraid of it.

Answer (score 2):

To show that two Lie algebras are not isomorphic, one usually finds an invariant (roughly, a property that is invariant under isomorphisms) that is different for two the Lie algebras. These include (including some Captain Llama suggested in the comments):

- the dimension;
- the dimension of the center;
- the isomorphism type (and dimension) of the derived subalgebra;
- whether the Lie algebra is nilpotent or solvable or semisimple or simple (nilpotence implies solvability, simplicity implies semisimplicity, but the converses of those statements arenot true; solvability and semisimplicity are mutually exclusive);
- the signature of the [Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) (Killing forms are nondegenerate precisely for semisimple Lie algebras, and such algebras of dimension (IIRC) $< \dim A_{17} = 323$ are determined up to isomorphism by this signature);
- isomorphism types (and in particular the dimensions) of the subalgebras in the [lower and upper central series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series).

To show that two Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{h}$ (say, of dimension $n$) *are* isomorphic, often the most straightforward method is just to construct an explicit isomorphism $\phi : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$. As Dietrich Burde points out in his good answer, if we choose bases of $\mathfrak{g, h}$, the homomorphism conditions $$\phi([e_i, e_j]) = [\phi(e_i), \phi(e_j)]$$ defines $\frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)$ quadratic conditions in the entries of the matrix representation of $\phi$, and often this system can be solved explicitly.

One can refine this method by adapting the choice of bases to the structure of the Lie algebras. For example, (at least over fields of characteristic $0$) if $\mathfrak{g, h}$ are not semisimple then their respective derived subalgebras, $\mathfrak{[g, g], [h, h]}$ are proper subalgebras. (Supposing the derived subalgebras have the same dimension, say $m$, since if not the Lie algebras are not isomorphic,) we can choose bases of $\mathfrak{g, h}$ adapated in the sense that $\mathfrak{[g, g]} = \operatorname{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_m\}$ and $\mathfrak{[h, h]} = \operatorname{span}\{f_1, \ldots, f_m\}$. Then, since $\phi(\mathfrak{[g, g]}) = \mathfrak{[h, h]}$, the matrix representation of $\phi$ must have the form $$[\phi] = \pmatrix{\ast&\ast\\&\ast} ,$$ where the block sizes are $m, n - m$. In particular, this forces the $m (n - m)$ of coefficients $a_{ij}$ with $i > m, j \leq m$, to vanish. This strategy and others like it can dramatically simplify the quadratic system in $a_{ij}$ and hence make it easier to construct an explicit isomorphism.

Finally, in small dimensions the Lie algebras (say, over $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$) have been classified up to isomorphism, and often you can quickly determine to which a given Lie algebra is isomorphic by eliminating all of the other possibilities.